# Getting numbers before and after strings using regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get the numbers in pandas data frame before and after certain keywords such as `word`, `words`, `page`, `pages`

```
jobtitle
english to spanish translations and voice over recording of four short video scripts (1100 words total)
south american spanish - 5 min video 900 words translation & voice over
translate manufacturing training video script from english to spanish (word document)
translating 100 pages to spanish
translate 1500 word document from english to spanish
translate 2225 word document from english to spanish
translate page 103
```

I tried something like:  `"(?:([0-9]?[0-9])[a-zA-Z ]{0,20}(?:word|words))"` but couldn't get them right.

Comment: Why so complicated? It seems for your example you could simply use `(\d+)\s*word[s]?`, see https://regex101.com/r/yNuOmJ/1

Comment: Then you use another one for `page`, and another one where the number comes after the word. Why does it have to be a single regex to cover all the cases?

Comment: No I just show that as an example, I also need one for regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alternation `|` to match either page or word followed by an optional s

To match 0 or more whitespace chars except newlines, you could use `[^\S\r\n]*`

```
\b(\d+)[^\S\r\n]*(?:page|word)s?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QrqjEo/1)